# MySQL Generally Available vs. Development Release

Tags: mysql

What is the difference between MySQL Generally Available release and Development Release? Can a Development Release be used for production database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stability, amount of testing done, featureset.

With dev release you get new features and new bugs. There is generally less information about problems.

I would never recommend using Dev release for production.